# Textbox changes when button is click visual basic

Tags: vba

need help , when i click the draw button the textbox (txt2 txt3 txt4) change to 0 instead of the number i put. heres my code

Public Class Form2
    Dim RndGen As New Random
    Dim N7, N5, N6 As Integer
    Dim N2, N3, N4 As Integer

```
Private Sub draw_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles draw.Click
    txt2.Text = N2
    txt3.Text = N3
    txt4.Text = N4
    txt5.Text = N5
    txt6.Text = N6
    txt7.Text = N7

    txt2.Focus()
    N5 = RndGen.Next(1, 10)
    N6 = RndGen.Next(1, 10)
    N7 = RndGen.Next(1, 10)

    If N2 = N5 Or N3 = N6 OrElse N4 = N7 Then
        MessageBox.Show("CONGRATS")
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

[image: Windows Form]

Answer (score 0):

From the code fragment you expose I think that N2 should read the value from txt2 and not set it. I feel that you actually reset the text boxes with zeros.

Comment: N2 is set to integer which is txt2.text. but why is it changing to zero when i click draw . it must be the number i put in textbox (txt2)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you read the text before the system has actually changed the contents of the edit box so you end up with 0. You should respond to TextChanged even which occurs after the text has changed.

Comment: Thanks i got the idea . i found it when you say it reads the N2 because of DIM N2 N3 ... as Integer which is zero